# Using something other than true or false in Javascript output

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, validation

I've got this piece of code for validating a registration form and I'm looking to clean up the output variables.  At the moment I have a true / false system to check the value of an input on blur and then check again when the button is pressed.

So what I want is the user to see an error message if they type the wrong thing in, but see a "Please add something in here" type of message if nothing i pressed.  The problem is that because the error is still set to false, so the original error message gets changed automatically but I don't really want that, so is there any other way of doing it by setting something else?  Here is an example of what I have with tru, false and now 'changed', but this doesn't work

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var regnameok = false;

// Name Validation
$('#regname').blur(function() {
    var regname=$(this).val();
    if(regname.length < 2) {
        $('.regNameStatus').html("Enter Your Name").removeClass("success").addClass("error");
        regnameok = changed;
    }
    else {
        $('.regNameStatus').html("Thanks").removeClass("error").addClass("success");
        regnameok = true;
    }
});
```

Thanks

Comment: It would be more clear if you can public it in here: http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: If you don't want boolean state then don't use a boolean. Use a string, or number, or object. Whatever you want

Comment: Ok to clarify, On button press if it is 'false' I want it to say "Please Enter Something", and if it's 'true' or 'changed' I want it to stay as it is

Comment: well you need to add another `else if` statement for what to do when it's false

Comment: So @musefan - You're saying if it's 'false' use 0, 'true' use 1 and 'changed' use 2?

Comment: @user2379000: That is certainly one option yes, I would probably do this too

Comment: You could use `false`, `true` and the string `'changed'`, noting that in an if test `if(regnameok)` both `true` and `'changed'` are truthy values...

Comment: Thanks @musefan - Worked perfectly - Thanks to all other repliers too